# insert multiple rows into mysql table - one column from constant value, other from an array

Tags: php, mysql, database

How do insert multiple rows into a mysql table, with one column remaining constant, and the other as an array.

```
//inserted profession into professions table, return id
$new_profession_id = mysql_insert_id(); 

$qualification_array = array();

foreach ($_POST['qualification'] as $qual){
    array_push($qualification_array, $qual);
}

$query = "???
```

now how would I insert this into the profession_has_qualification table? its got me stumped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$new_profession_id = mysql_insert_id(); 

foreach ($_POST['qualification'] as $qual){
   mysql_query("insert into TableName set pid = $new_profession_id, qualification = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($qual) . "'");
}
```

Comment: great thanks. I was wondering though - is it OK to make many queries like this? or should it be put into one?

Comment: @davivid: Query will run multiple times no matter what after all you want to add more than one record which is not possible with single query :)